# How to add content to categories woocomerce in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, categories

I want to add content to categories product woocomercer in wordpress, Like in post article. Thank you so much
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bT9El.png)

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to achieve what you want.

**An easy and very fast way** to get a new field to categories, is using the Advanced Custom Fields Plugin, which is recommended in the official wordpress documentation.

Advanced Custom Fields Plugin (free) :

https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/

After install and activating the plugin, you go in your Wordpress Backend to "Custom Fields" -> "Field Groups". Create a new field group and call it for example "Categories".

In the "Location" settings you set:
Show this field group if

**"Taxonomy Term" is equal to "category"**

Then you add a new field with field type "Text Area" and call it something like "Category Content".

After saving, you will have a new field in the edit screen of your category terms.
Just select your term (for example "uncategorized" and click "edit". Then you will see the new field and everything will be saved correctly if you like to do changes.